# create .sh files and fix it in the Linux commands

Tags: java, linux, bash

I've created a .sh file on Linux, and i need to put it in Linux Commands.
My final target is to execute it as "run time" using java.

Comment: please share what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just put the file into `/bin` with appropriate privilegies. But even better would be to put it into `src/main/resources` of your project and execute it from there, I don't see a reason why to pollute your `/bin` directory.

Answer (score 0):

To put command in "Linux Commands" you need to change the PATH variable, you can do this in .bashrc just like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/the/path/to/the/directory/with/your/command
```

After that it will be available for running (re-login is required). Another thing is that the file needs to be executable, you can do this with

```
chmod a+x script.sh
```

then you'll be able to do something like this from java

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("script.sh")
```